# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачку по информатике, нужно вывести с помощью питона

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу решить весь мозг сломала( [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На какой конкретно трудности сломался мозг?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы показать результаты ломания мозга? Как Вы уже решали задачу? Что не получается?

Comment: Я даже не представляю себе по какой формуле это решать(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это можно решить рекурсией:

```
def f(n, arr, x = 1):
    sum_ = 0
    for el in arr:
        if x + el < n:
            sum_ += 1
            sum_ += f(n, arr, x + el)
    return sum_

n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(f(n, arr))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)))) а можно еще вопросик по задачке?) если не отвлекаю конечно)

Comment: @Алиса можно, я не занят

Comment: Я вот обновила в теме вопроса задачку, она примерно из прошлой темы.... и тоже сложная немножко(

Comment: @Алиса во первых один вопрос - одна задача, во вторых без попыток решения я не буду отвечать. этот ответ исключение потому что данный вопрос показался интересным